# Python write asynchronously to database

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am trying to write to Cloud SQL (MySQL) from Dialogflow Fulfillment. The backend is hosted in App Engine and I am accessing Cloud SQL using Public IP (other apps are also using same DB so I do not have option to use Private IP at the moment). Basically everything is working but writing to DB takes longer than allowed session period so I get DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error on Dialogflow.

The thing is I do not need to wait for the data to be written in DB. So I am wondering if it is possible to use some asynchronous tricks to handle the writing processes.

For example:

```
.
.
.
# Take input from users.
# Save them in variables.
# Make a JSON file

write_to_db(JSON_file)
# Don't wait for the response from the above funciton
.
.
.
# Continue with the rest and return if necessary
```

Is there any ways to achieve this in python?

**EDIT**

Code that writes to Cloud SQL.

```
import sqlalchemy
import logging
import os

connection_name = ""
db_name = ""
db_user = ""
db_password = ""
driver_name = 'mysql+pymysql'
query_string = dict({"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(connection_name)})

.
.
.
def insert_reservation():
    REST_ID = "0010"
    RESV_ID = "0020"
    RESV_DT = "12082020"
    USER_ID = "1234"
    RESV_TM = "1040"
    RESV_PERSON_NU = "4"
    USER_COMMENT = "some Comment"
    stmt = sqlalchemy.text("INSERT INTO table_name (REST_ID, RESV_ID, RESV_DT, USER_ID, RESV_TM, RESV_PERSON_NU, USER_COMMENT) values ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}');".format(
        REST_ID,
        RESV_ID, 
        USER_ID,
        RESV_DT,
        RESV_TM,
        RESV_PERSON_NU,
        USER_COMMENT
    ))
    db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
      sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
          drivername=driver_name,
          username=db_user,
          password=db_password,
          database=db_name,
          query=query_string,
      ),
      pool_size=5,
      max_overflow=2,
      pool_timeout=30,
      pool_recycle=1800
    )
    try:
        with db.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(stmt)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("SQL Error: {}".format(str(e)))
        #return 'Error: {}'.format(str(e))
    
    return 'ok'
.
.
.
```

As mentioned before this works fine, but the only problem is, it is slow. Any suggestion to improve the speed or give it to another thread to handle it?

Comment: You could use any asynchronous job thing. rq, celery come to mind if you're hosting on regular VMs, and if you're hosting on Google, they have Cloud Tasks.

Comment: Other than external API calls (Cloud Tasks, Pub/Sub), can you suggest some python libraries that cloud do the job?

Comment: Depending on how you're hosting the app, you could just `threading.Thread(target=write_to_db, args=(JSON_file,)).start()` and hope for the best

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to write to Cloud SQL from Dialogflow?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I have added the code.